# Can we use PUSH instruction as ' PUSH AL '

Tags: x86-16

8086 Microprocessor Instruction.Can we use PUSH instruction as 'PUSH AL'? What is the syntax of PUSH instruction either its operand is 16 bit or 8 bit

Answer (score 5):

On 8086 `push` decrements the SP register by 2 and then writes a 16 bit value at the memory pointed to by the SP register. You cannot write `push al` because AL is an 8 bit value and push requires a 16 bit value. So you must write `push ax`.